# Is attr_accessor required in resource definition of chef lwrp?

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I created an LWRP using chefdk and following the documentation and a few blog posts to the letter.

**resource**

```
actions :install
default_action :install

provides :foo

attribute :name, :kind_of => String, :name_attribute => true
```

**provider**

```
provides :foo

def whyrun_supported?
  true
end

use_inline_resources

action :install do
  converge_by("install: #{@new_resource}") do
    execute "installation of: #{@new_resource.name}" do
      command "foo install #{@new_resource.name}"
    end
  end
end

def load_current_resource
  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::Foo.new @new_resource.name
  @current_resource.name = @new_resource.name
end
```

When using this LWRP in a cookbook, I would get the following error:

```
undefined method `name=' for Chef::Resource::Foo
```

The only way I could fix it was by adding `attr_accessor :name` to the resource definition. But I never saw this as a requirement in any documentation. From the documentation, I was assuming that Chef took care of setting `attr_accessor` on any attributes during resource/provider compilation. Can anyone confirm what I found or explain what was really happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def load_current_resource
  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::Foo.new @new_resource.name
  @current_resource.name = @new_resource.name
end
```

Your problem is here, `name` is supposed to be invariable (for current and new resource to match) as it identify the resource, you should not try to set `@current_resource.name`.

Remove this line and it should be ok without the accessor.

Comment: I used http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/01/07/creating-an-lwrp-part-2/ as a guide. That blog post shows setting 'name' using a method called 'name', as well as other attrs being set the same way. I just assumed that = would work as well. Is this Chef using 'method_missing' to create methods for attrs? Or is it Ruby saying = will only work with the use of 'attr_accessor'?

Comment: Sorry I can only answer for what I know from chef, I'm not a ruby expert, but as far as I understood attributes are set with methods (with a sub call to a method named set_or_return) to allow using them both way (access and assignation) You can have a look at the [chef code on github](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/resource/lwrp_base.rb#L75) if you're interested in the inners of chef.

Comment: After reading the code and performing a few tests, I can confirm that Chef is dynamically creating a setter/getter for each attribute and those methods should be called to set the values of the attributes in `load_current_resource`. I'm not sure if this says anything about what Chef considers to be idiomatic code, but they are not prescribing the use of readers and writers for attributes.

Comment: @glevine glad it helped, there's #chef channel on irc.freeware.net and a mailing list too where chef devs answer and talk if you want to dig the subject (see the tag wiki for links)

Comment: irc on previous comment is irc.freenode.net :/